# Using external JS libraries with Streamlit

Tags: streamlit

How can I use an external Video/Audio JS library like [Wavesurfer.js](https://wavesurfer-js.org/) to render and interact with my streamlit app?

Answer (score 1):

To use external JavaScript libraries inside of Streamlit, they provide the 'Streamlit Components' functionality:

https://docs.streamlit.io/en/stable/develop_streamlit_components.html#create-a-bi-directional-component

> A bi-directional Streamlit Component has two parts:
>
> A frontend, which is built out of HTML and any other web tech you like
> (JavaScript, React, Vue, etc.), and gets rendered in Streamlit apps
> via an iframe tag.
>
> A Python API, which Streamlit apps use to instantiate and talk to that
> frontend